# How to create a family tree structure of nodes?

Tags: views

I have to create a family tree in Drupal. I am trying to use tree views module to do the same.

I have 3 nodes (A, B and C) of the contact type (I have created custom node), whereas C is son of A (Father ) & B (Mother).

I need to show the same in a tree like structure.

I have used relationship module and made these relations:

- A isFatherof C
- B isMotherof C

How do I show them as a tree like structure? Something like so:

```
A - B
  |
  C
```

I have tried using the *trees views* module.

Comment: What do you mean "show them as a tree structure?"  Are you talking graphically or something in text?

Comment: yes graphically like a tree.

Comment: yes I am also looking for same concept, Allan or sudarshan, you guys have any idea how to build the tree structure? I am also searching for the concept... If, any idea pleas post..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've tried to use the [Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) module (there doesn't seem to be a "*trees views*" module ...). To my knowledge, that module cannot create a *graphical* visualisation of a tree structure.

I'd recommend to create such tree structure using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) diagrams, and use the [Graphviz Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/graphviz_filter) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> ... a little filter that treats input text as [DOT syntax](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) for [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), converts it using Graphviz tools to the [requested format(s)](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html) and renders it in HTML. It's useful to quickly create graphs dynamically from within Drupal nodes.

For more information, refer to the [Community Documentation about Graphing Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1389294), which has a list of modules for creating either *Static* or *Dynamic* Graph Diagrams.